# How do I type the pipe character on a MacBook Pro (Lion) with a Turkish-Q keyboard layout?

Tags: keyboard, macbook, keyboard-layout

I can't find the keyboard combination to make the | symbol. On snow leopard "shift+ı" worked. I've tried <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was on a turkish-q keyboard. The correct combination is strange, but  <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd><</kbd> worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Under Ubuntu 12.04 LTS running on PowerBook G4, I selected Macintosh layout. Then, I mapped the third level key binding to the right Apple key (Alt right). Once done, typing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>,<kbd>→</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> gives the pipe character.

Comment: Are you serious? That is not usable. Is there any other option?

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd> did the trick for me.

Using a windows-oriented (has a windows button) keyboard for nordics.